# In bash, why does if [ 1 ] not fail?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

In shell scripting (`bash`) why does the conditional get satisfied

```
if [ 1 ]
then
 echo should not enter
fi

#Output
should not enter
```

Comment: Because 1 is equivilent to true

Comment: Good question. It's nice to see people not being afraid to ask the basics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The square brackets in bash are equivalent to calling `test` with the arguments within the brackets. `man test` says that

> STRING equivalent to -n STRING

and

> -n STRING
>       the length of STRING is nonzero

, and 1 is not an empty string. `if [ 0 ]`, `if [ false ]` and `if [ no ]` have the same result, but `if [ "" ]` has not.

Answer (score 2):

What may not be obvious is that these two are very different:

```
if [ false ]
```

and

```
if false
```

The first, as [thiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108462/in-bash-why-does-if-1-not-fail/8108502#8108502) and [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108462/in-bash-why-does-if-1-not-fail/8108484#8108484) say, implicitly checks if the *string* `false` is empty. The second version tests the exit status of the *command* `false`. (The testing of an exit status isn't literally a true/false test. It checks for success or failure as represented by numeric codes. As you can imagine, the exit status of `false` is always failure. That's its job.)

For more on all of this, the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals) on [Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/) is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Because `1` is not an empty string; it has one character in it, which is the numeral "1".